# Ubuntu 17.10 Gnome not honoring blank screen settings

Tags: gnome, 17.10, gnome-power-manager

I've been using Ubuntu Gnome for around 5 years, and recently upgraded to 17.10. With this release, I've noticed a problem I cannot seem to resolve.

Under the "Power" settings is an option to "Blank Screen" after a specified interval. Since I've updated to 17.10, this value is ignored; the screen never blanks.

I am using GDM for my display manager, with Wayland as the display server. I do not have gnome-screensaver installed.

I can use `<Super>L` to lock the screen, and this works, but I'd prefer the autoblanking behavior.

(Interestingly, on a laptop on which I did a fresh install of Ubuntu 17.10, this seems to work fine, which indicates to me it is potentially an upgrade issue.)

Comment: Interestingly, after logging out of my session and back in... it seems to be working. I also noticed that the behavior of the top bar updated to what I see on my laptop (adapting color to the application currently open). However... after a lock, and unlock, my session crashed within 1 minute, so I'm not closing this as solved yet.